# rails polymorphic add using <<

Tags: polymorphism, ruby-on-rails-4.1

My new rails 4.1 project has the following polymorphic associations.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, as: :line_itemable
end
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :line_itemable, polymorphic: true
end
class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, as: :line_itemable
end
```

I am trying to migrate some old data so I have in my seeds.rb file

```
neworder = Order.create do |order|
  ...
end
neworder.line_items << LineItem.create do |li|
  ...
end
```

The << has always worked for me in the past.  In my old system I didn't have the shipments class so I had

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
end
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

and << just worked.  Now, I have been able to make the migration work by using

```
neworder = Order.create do |order|
  ...
end
newlineitem = LineItem.create do |li|
  ...
end
newlineitem.update_attribute(:line_itemable, neworder)
```

This just does not seem like the rails way to do things.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in migration you do not use class from app/models, but the one inside your migration. Check via `rails console` what's in the `line_itemable_type` column for chosen `LineItem`. Instead of `Order` you will see `YourMigrationName::Order`, which explains everything.

In general your approach is correct though - it is good practice to define code in migration if it requires it to work. There is just one gotcha with polymorphic association :) I think there is no 'best' way to deal with it - one can set `type` manually (this is what I would have done), one can craft sql query manually (if you need to create a lot of objects this is probably the way to go, but then shouldn't be placed in migration IMO). You can for example set type like this:

`newlineitem = LineItem.create do |li|
  li.line_itemable_type = 'Order'
  li.line_itemable_id = neworder.id
  # other stuff you have
end`